# "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Tags: asp.net

I have an application that displays PDF files via Crystal Reports in a new window to the user. This works perfectly on my development machine and when accessing the site directly on the production server (remote desktop running browser installed on server) but when i access the site from the out side over the internet i get the error. Other reports display fine and this report used to work until i recently made some changes and re-installed the site. All code is in `try ... catch` but not info is being written to my error files. Cant figure out why it would work locally on the server but not over the internet and only this one report.

Have tried the `System.Web` attributes `maxRequestLength` and `executionTimeout`.

The Server is:
**Windows Web Server 2008
IIS 7
Framework 4**

Comment: what is the http status?

Comment: Can you connect via telnet to your IIS-server?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue with the crystal report file, i never found out exactly why but i narrowed it down to one of the fields causing the problem, remove the field and no problem. I think it may have been linked to the reports xml based data source but cannot prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a firewall setting. Please make sure your firewall explicitly allows incoming connections to the TCP port 80 (or 443 for https, or anything else if you are accessing the site via another port) and try again.